# MVC WebAPI Route and Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set up a WebAPI project using RESTful principles, but I need help with route configuration.

here is the routes that i have declared in the WebAPIConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Child Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}/{child}",
            defaults: new { version = "1", action = "Index", child = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi With Version",
            routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { version = "1", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { version = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is the controller action declaration:

```
public class EventsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/v1/Events
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string version)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Here is the request that I came calling that is not finding the controller action:
   GET /api/v1/Events HTTP/1.1

Can anyone show me why I am getting a not found error when i use the above and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the default action you have declared (`action = "Index"`). If you remove that it will work fine. (because you haven't specified an `{action}` parameter in your route it will always do the default, which is Index, which doesn't exist).

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Child Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}/{child}",
            defaults: new { version = "1", child = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi With Version",
            routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { version = "1", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Hi, just removed the "DefaultAPI" route and tried again but no joy. Does the routes defined in the RouteConfig matter here?

Comment: I think you missed my point. On the first 2 routes, you have specified a default *action*. That is what you need to remove. You can keep the DefaultApi route itself. I just omitted the DefaultApi route from my answer as it doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: @StephenCossgrove Did you try just removing the action?